# Returning a variable from closure

Tags: javascript, closures

How can I get the return value of that.whatever back from the closure?  Instead of:

```
this.setCanvas = function(files){
  var numItems = files.length - 1;
  this.items = {};

  var i = 0;
  for(i=0;i<=numItems;i++)
  {
    var file = files[i];
    var reader = new FileReader(); 

    reader.onload = (function(i) { 
      return function(e) { 
        var something = that.whatever();
        items[i] = something;
      }; 
    })(i);  

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

console.log(items); 
}
```

I need items[i] defined.  If I console.log items[i] outside of the closure it is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can augment your code to keep track of the number of files loaded. This way, when the last file has been loaded, you can invoke an ultimate completion handler:

```
  this.setCanvas = function(files) {
    var numItems = files.length - 1;
    var itemsLoaded = 0; // Initialize to zero

    var items = [];

    var i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<=numItems;i++) {

      var file = files[i];
      var reader = new FileReader(); 

      reader.onload = (function(i) { 
        return function(e) { 
          var something = that.whatever();
          items[i] = something;

          if(++itemsLoaded == numItems) {
            // At this point all files will have been loaded.
            allLoaded();
          }
        }; 
      })(i);  

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    function allLoaded() {
      // Now we can analyze the results
      console.log(items); 
    }
  }
```

I also changed `items` to be an `Array` instead of an `Object`.

Also if you want to be a little more clever, you could decrement `numItems` and check for zero instead of creating a new `itemsLoaded` variable.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up passing items out via a function.  Your example got me moving in the right direction.  I still don't understand all this fully but that's a whole nother issue ; )

Comment: Just made a minor update. Instead of doing `this.items = []`, I just made it a variable instead, this allows the closure (handler) to access it more easily; otherwise the `onload` handler would not know which `this` to use when trying get ahold of `items`. FYI, the `onload` handler is called by the JavaScript engine and you'll find that the `this` reference points to the `reader` instance instead.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't the *closure;* it's the *callback.* Whatever needs to use the value of `that.whatever` needs to be executed **in the callback.**

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you need to change here. First set this.items to an array. Next assign this to self so it can be referenced in the closure. Next assign the something to self.items[i] instead of items[i]. Finally use this.items in the console.log

```
this.setCanvas = function(files){
  var self = this;
  var numItems = files.length - 1;
  this.items = [];

  var i = 0;
  for(i=0;i<=numItems;i++)
  {
    var file = files[i];
    var reader = new FileReader(); 

    reader.onload = (function(i) { 
      return function(e) { 
        var something = that.whatever();
        self.items[i] = something;
      }; 
    })(i);  

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

    console.log(this.items); 
}
```